# How to decode json in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following codes in my controller:

```
public function actionCabinet($id){

    $this->render('cabinet', array('model'=>$this->loadJson($id)) );

}

    public function loadJson($id)
    {

        $jsonfile=ChForms::model()->findByPk($id, array("select"=>"json"));
        $decodedJson=json_decode($jsonfile, true);
        return $decodedJson;

    }
```

Data is saved in json field in ChForm in json format. I am going to convert it to array. When I run this application, it displays following error message:

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($jsonfile);`, is it a valid `JSON`?

Comment: Yes, it is. var_dump($jsonfile) is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
 public function loadJson($id)
{

    $jsonfile=ChForms::model()->findByPk($id);
    $decodedJson=json_decode($jsonfile->json, true);
    return $decodedJson;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use json_encode like below,

```
public function loadJson($id)
{

    $jsonfile=ChForms::model()->findByPk($id, array("select"=>"json"));
    $decodedJson=json_encode($jsonfile, true);
    return $decodedJson;

}
```

Comment: json_encode is used for convert an array to json format.